# How can I make these CSS absolute positions work in IE?

Tags: css, css-position

Please look at the code below. If you look at the diagram of the body, each colour represents different content on the right. However, these links won't work in IE, I assume due to the CSS I have written.

Can anyone shed some light on how I can replicate this in IE?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="male">
    <img src="male1.png" alt="male1 Compensation Calculator" title="male" width="130" height="300" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-117" /></p>
    <div class="head"><span class="whole fakelink"></span></div>
    <div class="neck"><span class="whole fakelink"></span></div>
    <div class="arm1"><span class="whole fakelink"></span></div>
    <div class="arm2"><span class="whole fakelink"></span></div>
    <div class="torso"><span class="whole fakelink"></span></div>
    <div class="legs"><span class="whole fakelink"></span></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.head {
    position: absolute;
    width: 70px;
    margin-left: 31px;
    height: 70px;
}
div.neck {
    position: absolute;
    height: 6px;
    width: 18px;
    margin: 70px 0px 0px 56px;
}
div.arm1 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 105px;
    width: 30px;
    margin: 77px 0px 0px 100px;
}
div.arm2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 105px;
    width: 30px;
    margin: 77px 0px 0px 0px;
}
div.torso {
    position: absolute;
    height: 118px;
    width: 70px;
    margin: 77px 0px 0px 31px;
}
div.legs {
    position: absolute;
    height: 105px;
    width: 69px;
    margin: 195px 0px 0px 31px;
}
.whole {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
}
.fakelink {
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.fakelink:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration:none;   
}
```

Comment: which version of ie do you have issue with 7 8 or 9

Comment: Define "don't work". Does anything at all happen? The only thing I see wrong is that you are closing a `p` element that doesn't seem to exist. By the way, you don't have to specify a unit when using 0 in CSS. 0 in any unit will always be the same as 0 in any other unit. But of course that's not the problem. :)

Comment: Older versions of IE do have problems with absolute position, yes. If you must support it, here is an article that may help: http://www.nixsoft.co.uk/index.php?file=/articles/absolute-fudge.page

Comment: Oh, I just looked at the site, and my question now is: why don't you use a client-side image map?

Comment: imge mapping wasn't used as i was using another content slider earlier that didn't play ball. i have been using IE9 but assume that 8 and below will also have this issue

Comment: IE9 does not work like IE8 which doesn't work like IE7 which doesn't work like IE6 and none of them work like the other far more modern  browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of only two solutions to fix this issue, though they both ultimately come down to needing a background:

**Option 1**
Set a `background-color` on `.fakelink` that is not transparent. Whilst clearly in your case this wouldn't be very helpful it will illustrate the need for a background.

If you were only needing to support IE9, I would suggest using rgba with a low alpha opacity:

```
.fakelink{ background-colour: rgba(255,255,255,0.01) }
```

**Option 2**
 Use a small transparent .png or .gif and tile it as the `background-image` for `.fakelink`

Comment: thanks for this solution! I needed to support as many IE versions as possible so used option 2 which worked!